# Sharing a Image does not work

Tags: android

I have a function that share an screenshot that I just saved to desk, while the file is definitely there, and the sharing activity load correctly,  the image is never included, why is this?

```
private File lastScreenShot = null;

public void onShare(float top, float left, float width, float height){
    if(lastScreenShot == null){
        saveScreenShot(top, left, width, height);
    }
    if (!lastScreenShot.exists()) {
        return;
    }
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, lastScreenShot);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out what I created!");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Your Pretty Creation!"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the content resolver doesn't know about your file because you just created it.

Insert it into the database and send it like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, lastScreenShot.getAbsolutePath());
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);  // Pass in a Uri not a File
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out what I created!");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Your Pretty Creation!"));
```

Also, be aware the startActivity can throw a `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException` in this case.